# What is browser fingerprinting and why should I want to avoid it?

Tags: security, browser, tor, fingerprint, protected

What is browser-fingerprinting and why shoould I want to avoid it?

If that is related, I am already using adblock and do-not-track.

Comment: Try [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Comment: Google "What is browser fingerprinting": [Browser Fingerprints: A Big Privacy Threat](http://www.pcworld.com/article/192648/browser_fingerprints.html), [Browser Fingerprinting: 9 Facts](http://www.darkreading.com/risk-management/browser-fingerprinting-9-facts/d/d-id/1112056?) and many more links ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I am not familiar enough with this community. Is googleability a reason not to ask a question?

Comment: @Den, questions should show a research effort and should pose a solveable problem related to computer software or hardware. See also [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) in the help.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 3):

Part of your hardware/software configuration can be traced by the websites you visit. For example a website can detect:

- Flash version.
- Web browser (IE, Chrome, Mozilla, etc.)
- Plugins in use on the browser
- Screen resolution
- Language
- Timezone
- OS (Windows XP, 7, 8, Linux, OSX, IOS, Android)
- Java version
- Fonts installed on your PC

Gathering all that information, a unique profile (a fingerprint) can be created and a history of the behavior of the profile stored (have this profile clicked ads in the past? which kind of ads? how long this profile stays?, etc...)

Next time that unique profile visits the website the system can determine which ads should be shown to him.

Answer (score 0):

> "A browser fingerprint is information collected about a remote
>   computing device for the purpose of identification. Fingerprints can
>   be used to fully or partially identify individual users or devices
>   even when cookies are turned off."

Think of it as a unique identifier for you browser. It could potentially be used in online advertising.